# Multiple commands in powershell

Tags: powershell

In powershell, how do you run multiple commands that might take different amount of time to complete
Let's say you have
command1: print pdf file.pdf
command2: scp file.pdf C:/abc/
command3: notepad log.txt

Does powershell wait for command1 to complete before starting command2?
If not, how do I wait until command1 is complete?

Comment: Please update the question with the actual commands as the current answer is _it depends_ and _it depends_

Comment: Yes, but the process doesnt. Meaning you can run a command, and as long as that command run successfully itll go onto the next. Even if notepad.exe hasnt loaded all the way

Comment: @Abraham, I want to wait for the command to be completed. How can I scp a file if the file hasn't been printed completely yet.